# Как отключить выполнение одной функции jquery в IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток. Есть файл main.js в котором отображены все функции используемые на сайте. Все работает во всех браузерах, но одна функция категорически отказывается работать корректно в IE.Как отключить только ее?Не знаю как правильно прописать условие. чтобы проверялся браузер и отключал ее выполнение. Вариант в условным комментарием не подойдет, так как не хотелось бы выносить функцию в тело страницы либо же в отдельный файл.Вот функция

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();  
    $(".logos").css({
    "transform" : "translate(0%," + st/3 + "%"
}); 
});
```

Спасибо заранее за советы.

Comment: Какая функция в каком ИЕ?

Comment: функция описана выше, а выполнение в любом Internet Explorere, так как она не совсем корректно работает в них.

Comment: `$(window).scroll()`? У меня даже на ИЕ5 работает

Comment: Дело не в скролле самом!а в том, что эта функция работает так, что когда скроллится страница, то элемент опускается потихоньку вниз(легкий паралакс), так вот во всех браузерах это работает нормально и плавно, а в IE он опускается(элемент), но рывками, как будто по ступенькам на велосипеде едет.ПОэтому мне проще отключить ее для IE, но не знаю как, так как исправить пробовал это всяко для корректной работы в IE, но не получается..

Answer (score 1):

Посидел, поразмышлял и вот что вышло..

```
function browserDetectJS() {
var
    browser = new Array();
//Opera
    if (window.opera) {
        browser[0] = "Opera";
        browser[1] = window.opera.version();
    }
        else 
//Chrome    
        if (window.chrome) {
            browser[0] = "Chrome";
        }
            else
//Firefox
            if (window.sidebar) {
                browser[0] = "Firefox";
            }
                else
//Safari 
                    if ((!window.external)&&(browser[0]!=="Opera")) {
                        browser[0] = "Safari";
                    }
                        else
//IE
                        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                            browser[0] = "MSIE";
                            if (window.navigator.userProfile) browser[1] = "6"
                                else 
                                    if (window.Storage) browser[1] = "8"
                                        else 
                                            if ((!window.Storage)&&(!window.navigator.userProfile)) browser[1] = "7"
                                                else browser[1] = "Unknown";
                        }
    if (!browser) return(false)
        else return(browser);
}
```

так можно определить браузер, а уж вставить это в функцию не так трудно.Может кому пригодится.Всем спасибо.

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что Opera определится как Chrome. Проверку на оперу нужно ставить после хрома.